# django restricting edit and delete with generic view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I wrote edit and delete view, and they work. But I soon realized anyone can edit and delete any post. I want only user who created the post to be able to delete and edit the post.

```
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
   model = Post
   form_class = PostForm
   template_name = 'main/edit.html'

   def form_valid(self, form):
      self.object = form.save(commit=False)
      self.object.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())

   @method_decorator(login_required)
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     return super(PostUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)



class PostDeleteView(DeleteView):
   model = Post

   def get_success_url(self):
      return "/" 

   @method_decorator(login_required)
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      return super(PostDeleteView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add object level permission to generic view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326938/add-object-level-permission-to-generic-view)

Comment: I tried it but didn't work unfortunately, I guess I should review documentation on the generic view maybe I missed some info

Comment: @louis what did you edit?i don't see the difference

Comment: I added more accurate tags. sorry, I forgot to add comment.

Comment: Oh..do you have any idea how I should approach fixing this issue? I read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/ but it's not there. I"m new to django. I think its a simple solution but getting not fixed

Comment: @louis wow django community is harsh eh

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `get_queryset` method for your views, and filter the queryset so that only objects belonging to that user are included. For example, for your update view you would do:

```
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(PostUpdateView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
```