# Control access to a page in UpdateView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I want to control that only the superuser and for example the teacher, can access a page inherited from `UpdateView` and redirect others to the `/404` page.

My class in `views.py` :

```py
class Edit_news(UpdateView):
    model = News
    form_class = edit_NewsForm
    template_name = "profile/Edit_news.html"
```

URL of class in `urls.py` :

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import Edit_news

urlpatterns = [
    path("edit-news/<pk>", Edit_news.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Can you please mention "Edit_news.html" is the page that needs to be accessed only by superuser

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

You can override [View.dispatch()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) which is the entrypoint of any HTTP methods to check first the user.

> **`dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)`**
>
> The view part of the view – the method that accepts a request argument plus arguments, and returns a HTTP response.
>
> The default implementation will inspect the HTTP method and attempt to delegate to a method that matches the HTTP method; a GET
> will be delegated to `get()`, a POST to `post()`, and so on.

```
class Edit_news(UpdateView):
    ...

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if (
            request.user.is_superuser
            or request.user.has_perm('app.change_news')  # If ever you attach permissions to your users
            or request.user.email.endswith('@teachers.edu.org')  # If the email of teachers are identified by that suffix
            or custom_check_user(request.user)  # If you have a custom checker
        ):
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return HttpResponseForbidden()

    ...
```

If you want it to be different for HTTP GET and HTTP POST and others, then override instead the [specific method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.BaseUpdateView).

> **`class django.views.generic.edit.BaseUpdateView`**
>
> Methods
>
> `get(request, *args, **kwargs)`
>
> `post(request, *args, **kwargs)`

Related reference:

- [Add object level permission to generic view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326938/add-object-level-permission-to-generic-view)

### Solution 2

You can also try [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) (the class-based implementation of [user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test)).

```
class Edit_news(UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):  # Some mixins in django-auth is required to be in the leftmost position (though for this mixin, it isn't explicitly stated so probably it is fine if not).
    raise_exception = True  # To not redirect to the login url and just return 403. For the other settings, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin

    def test_func(self):
        return (
            self.request.user.is_superuser
            or self.request.user.has_perm('app.change_news')  # If ever you attach permissions to your users
            or self.request.user.email.endswith('@teachers.edu.org')  # If the email of teachers are identified by that suffix
            or custom_check_user(self.request.user)  # If you have a custom checker
        )

    ...
```